# regular expression string with set of numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string s1

s1 is like:  DIST:AGT:SEXXXX\DIST:AFTER:EXT:YYYYY\Agent

XXXX and YYYYY are not fixed, they can be whatever

XXXX: numbers, length from 4 to 6

YYYYY: numbers, length from 4 to 6

I have another string s2.

I want to verify if S2.Contains(s1), but I can't do it like this because I don't know the value of XXXX and YYYYY.

Do you have any suggastions?

Comment: Can you please post more code and a more clear explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: why a regex? `s2.indexOf(s1) != -1`?

Comment: When you say _if this string exists in another string S2_  are you talking about the entire string `s` or just the number sets?  If the former then just use `string.Contains`, for the latter you might need a regular expression, but it's not clear.  Maybe if you included some examples.

Comment: In fact these numbers change, that's why I would like to have a pattern that independent of the numbers. So I can't use string.Contains

Comment: s1 is an expression

Comment: Edit your question so that its very specific to what you need answered. Provide some example strings for your parameters so we can see what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it's more clear

Comment: So you just need to check if `XXXX` or `YYYYY` exist in this other `string s2`?

Comment: no the entire string s1

Comment: @AbirBY, you should provide some examples that pass and some that don't.

Comment: Okay, so you just want to check if `XXXX` and `YYYYY` contain a SET of numbers? Or if they contain any numbers which are in a pre-defined set? The wording of your question is really confusing.

Comment: No, in fact let's say I have users SE, so every user id is like SEXXXX, where XXXX are numbers. Same for YYYYY.
So I just want a regular expression for s1 that includes these variables.

Comment: I edited the question, I think it was miss undrestood

Comment: You have string s1. How come you don't know the value of XXXX and YYYYY? It's confusing.

Comment: @ccf cz I will be searching in a file for that string s1, without knowing the value of XXXX and YYYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you would use regex for is to match the numbers in your string.

`\d` matches a decimal number, (0-9), and `{4,6}` means to match the previous number 4 to 6 times.

To get a number in your string, you would use the regex pattern `@"\d{4,6}"`

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var s1 = @"DIST:AGT:SE1111\DIST:AFTER:EXT:22222\Agent";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s1, @"\d{4,6}");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
Console.ReadKey(false);
```

That sample code will print:

> 1111
>   22222

You would probably use the [String.Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) to actually check if another string contains those numbers.

---

Also be warned that this is a very simple regex.  If numbers of length 4-6 digits occur in other parts of your input string other than after `SE` and after `EXT:`, then it **will** find those numbers too, and you might need to make your regex more fancy.

---

After your edit:

If you have `s1`, then you wouldn't even need to know what the numbers are to simply call `s2.Contains(s1)`.

Do you perhaps need to **build** s1 based on the numbers?  In that case, I'd use [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var s1 = String.Format(@"DIST:AGT:SE{0}\DIST:AFTER:EXT:{1}\Agent", 1111, 22222);
```

---

Do you need to simply make sure that `s2` merely contains the pattern as laid out by `s1`?  In that case, you simply can use `Regex.IsMatch`

```
var s2 = @"DIST:AGT:SE1111\DIST:AFTER:EXT:22222\Agent";

var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(s2, @"DIST:AGT:SE\d{4,6}\\DIST:AFTER:EXT:\d{4,6}\\Agent");
```

be extra careful that the `\` in your pattern need to be escaped, for the regex language in addition to the c# language.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s1, @"\d{4,6}")`

Comment: I edited the question, I think it was not clear

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  ah, I suppose OP did say that the numbers were between 4 and 6 digits long.  Fixed.

Comment: @AbirBY In that case. why doesn't `S2.Contains(s1)` work?

Comment: because I want something general, without putting a value to XXXX or YYYYY

Comment: I will be searching in a file for that string s1, without knowing the value of XXXX and YYYYY

Comment: @AbirBY: You just need to search for the pattern in string s2. If yes, then s2 contains s1: `bool isContain = Regex.IsMatch(s1, @"DIST:AGT:SE(\d{4,6})\\DIST:AFTER:EXT:(\d{4,6})\\Agent");`